# How to send parameters with href

Tags: asp.net, listview, href, detailsview

I'm developing a web application in asp.NET using C# and EntityDataSource.
I have a listview to show a list of product, i want to redirect to another form that has the details of the product selected (you can select the name or image of the product). The redirection occurs successfully but the product in the detailview is always the same (the fist one).

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="">
        <td>
                <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />

        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="ListPriceLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ListPrice") %>' />
        </td>
        <td>
             <a href='<%# String.Format("Product.aspx?id={0}", Eval("ProductID")) %>' >
              <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />  
            </a>

        </td>
        <td>

            <a href='Product.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("productID") %>'  >
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# String.Format("~/ImageProduct.ashx?id={0}", Eval("ProductID")) %>' runat="server" />
            </a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="ThumbnailPhotoFileNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ThumbnailPhotoFileName") %>' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Any help ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you populating product ListView in the Page_Load method? If so add if(!this.IsPostBack) to that block to avoid the product selection getting affected.

Comment: Sorry am new in asp.NET ! How can i populate it in Page_Load ? @Vishwanath

Comment: If you are dynamically populating the ListView on CodeBehind(aspx.cs file) then you can use Databinding (Refer to "How to Populate a ListView Web Server Control"  http://goo.gl/75Qzg)

And if you call the listview databinder inside Page_Load then you need to take care of PostBack which calls Page_Load whenever click on any post back button. To avoid reloading of ListView and resetting of your selections enclose the list binder inside (!this.PostBack). If you are new to PostBack, Databinding I suggest you to spend some time studying that to help understanding my comment.

Comment: I need help with that, how can i get the parameter sent in the redirection ? (ProductID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify this. You have a List View of products and when you click the link of the particular product in the list, your page will be redirected to a page containing the details of the particular product in DetailsView. Is that correct?

In this case, you simply add a QueryString in your DetailsView

Example:

```
<asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="0" Name="ProductID" 
                QueryStringField="ID" />
```